# JIRA Alternatives for Websphere v8.5

Tags: jira, websphere-8

I am trying to install JIRA and on IBM WAS v8.5 and it seems to fail in relation to needing an older version of Javax.servlet...

> Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.atlassian.jira.jira-invite-user-plugin [55]: Unable to resolve 55.0: missing requirement [55.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.atlassian.activeobjects.external) [caused by: Unable to resolve 32.0: missing requirement [32.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=2.4.0))]

So the question is, are there any good alternatives for JIRA that can be installed on WAS8.5

Comment: Why websphere? you have some extra money and like getting kicked in the teeth? (every experience I've had with WAS felt like that).

Comment: I agree, unfortunately large corporations like to control the containers used.